# FileStream in a try and catch, how critical is it to close the reader?

Tags: c#, try-catch

I want to make sure to close the reader after creating a reader when there is an exception. So I want to include a finally bracket to this try and catch. But I can't close it in the finally bracket unless I have the reader declared outside above the try bracket. But if I do that I won't be catching any exceptions when creating the reader. I am not sure how critical it is to close the reader or not.

```
XmlSerializer xmlSr = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ProjectObject>));
try
{
    FileStream reader = new FileStream(mTextFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    List<ProjectObject> addProjects = (List<ProjectObject>)xmlSr.Deserialize(reader);
    mSharedDriveLocalProjects = addProjects;
    reader.Close();
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Failed to load XML file");
}
```

The above is my code. Is it better to have it this way?

```
XmlSerializer xmlSr = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ProjectObject>));
FileStream reader = new FileStream(mTextFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
try
{
    List<ProjectObject> addProjects = (List<ProjectObject>)xmlSr.Deserialize(reader);
    mSharedDriveLocalProjects = addProjects;
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Failed to load XML file");
}
finally
{
    reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: I would wrap the FileStream around a `using(){}` personally to take advantage of the `Auto Disposing` of the object. this will handle the closing as well

Comment: Any reason you must you `try/finally` instead of `using(...)`?

Comment: I guess I want to use try/catch to catch the exception to displace the exception message. I know I don't have it written like that right now but that is the plan

Comment: It is critical for SO sanity to dispose all disposable objects. Otherwise more people will flood SO with "why I'm getting file locked exception"... Otherwise if you don't care - shutdown of the app will cleanup all non-closed files/handles anyway - so survivable, not recommended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Using Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) is here to solve these dilemmas

```
 XmlSerializer xmlSr = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ProjectObject>));
 using(FileStream reader = new FileStream(mTextFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
 {
     try
     {
         List<ProjectObject> addProjects = (List<ProjectObject>)xmlSr.Deserialize(reader);
         mSharedDriveLocalProjects = addProjects;
     }
     catch
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Failed to load XML file");
     }
}
```

Any disposable object declared and created in a using statement is disposed at the exit of the block (the dispose method of the object is called and this method usually takes care to clean up everything, including the closure of the file)

Note that a using statement is like a try/finally, so if you want to catch the exception and show a nice error message to your user or log it somewhere, you still need to explicitly prepare a try/catch block around your code.

Answer (score 2):

C# and .NET library provide a nice idiomatic way of doing this with `using` keyword:

```
using (var reader = new FileStream(mTextFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)) {
    try {
        ...
    } catch {
        ...
    }
}
```

Since `FileStream` is `IDisposable`, and because its `Dispose()` method calls `Close()`, wrapping `reader` into `using` block provides a convenient method of ensuring that the stream is closed after you are done with it.